# TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: firebase, react-native

How can I solve it? Is the file incorrect?

TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined, js engine: hermes

```
import  firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig ={
    apiKey: "******",
    authDomain: "*****",
    databaseURL: "*****",
    projectId: "****",
    storageBucket: "****",
    messagingSenderId: "****",
    appId: "****",
    measurementId: "****"
  };
  
  console.log(firebase);
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  export const app = firebase.app();
  export const db = firebase.firestore();
  export const database = firebase.database();
```

Comment: According to [firebase API documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#multiple-projects), it is suggest to use `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";`

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the syntax from the legacy namespaced SDK instead of the current modular SDK. Take a look at the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for how to update to the latest syntax. However, because you are using React Native, you should probably look at [`@react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io) instead which does still use the legacy syntax and calls out to the Android and iOS SDKs from JavaScript where needed.